# How can I use ZendX Jquery outside zend, like in CI or raw PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zendx

i want to use zendx jquery with CI, but i see that it used zend view with it. please let me know can i use it as standalone package like many other zend library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ZendX_JQuery lib without Zend_View and/or Zend_Form components. They are really meant to be helpers for those. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.html

Comment: is any think out there like ZendX_JQuery lib, i can use with CI or raw php

Comment: @user first result on Google is http://jquery.hohli.com/ - I have never used that and cannot say if it is similar to what ZF offers, but I'd be surprised if there isnt any other libs like that.